# A python server that executes python scripts

Tags: python, server-side-scripting, simplehttpserver

I'm doing a python class this semester, and I'd like to add graphical user interfaces to my programs in the form of web pages. Partly I can't be bothered to learn Tkinter, partly I'm just challenging myself, and partly I just like coding interfaces in HTML/JS.

I know the basics on creating HTTP servers with SimpleHTTPServer, but what I need is a way for my web pages to fire ajax commands to python scripts on the server, which will then be executes server side, and then receive the script output. Kind of like how [Sage](http://sagemath.org/) does things.

How can I create an extension for SimpleHTTPServer that I can then use to serve up the outputs of python scripts? I need a solution that's very general, so that given any python script I write, I can easily wrap it in some sort of interface, put it in the server's folder, and not have to do anything else but call it with AJAX, and my server will handle the rest.

My current idea is to have a `ServerSideScript` class that my scripts can extend, with a single function called `output`. Every script I have should contain a subclass of ServerSideScript named Script. When the server is asked to serve, for example, *foo.py*, it notices the extension and does something like:

```
if self.path[-3:]: == ".py":
    return getScriptOutput(self.path)

...

def getScriptOutput(self, path):
    from path import Script # obviously not going to work, since path is a string
    return Script().output()
```

That can't work for the reason pointed out in the comment, I'm aware of things like the [import_module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) function, but importing seems like an ugly way to do this to begin with.

What's recommended?

Comment: Have you seen [CGIHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html)?

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's default, right? I can't necessarily install extra modules on a school computer.

Comment: Why not use a proper webserver, and a micro framework like Flask?

Comment: @JackM: That is part of the standard library, yes. See the link.

Comment: @DanielRoseman See above comment - but also I'd quite like to write the code myself, if it can be kept reasonably minimal.

Comment: @MartijnPieters CGIHTTPServer looks perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python comes with batteries included; [`CGIHTTPServer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html) will run Python scripts using the CGI standard:

> The `CGIHTTPServer` module defines a request-handler class, interface compatible with `BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler` and inherits behavior from `SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` but can also run CGI scripts.

It'll run Python scripts as long as they have a `.py` or `.pyw` extension, and are executable; other paths mapping to files are treated as regular files and have their content served instead.

You may be interested in the [`cgi`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html) and [`cgitb`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgitb.html) modules as well, to help ease CGI script development.

Comment: [CGIHTTPServer tutorial](http://pointlessprogramming.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/python-cgi-tutorial-1/).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [IPython notebooks](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) - it essentially gives you a web-based interactive Python shell, which even integrates with matplotlib etc. You can save Python scripts as notebooks, add text inbetween statements etc.

[image]

You can also use the [nbviewer](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/) if you want to share the output, but not the interactivity.

Comment: I'm doing this for the fun of coding it, not for the practical value. But thanks.